# How to get instance of model in UpdateAPIView django REST?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model `Request` is below

```
class Request(models.Model):
    PENDING = 1
    APPROVE = 2
    REJECT = 3
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (PENDING, 'Pending'),
        (APPROVE, 'Approve'),
        (REJECT, 'Reject')
    )
    seller = models.ForeignKey(
        Seller,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='requests',
    )
    owner = models.OneToOneField(
        UserProfile,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='request',
    )
    reject_reason = models.TextField(default='')
    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(STATUS_CHOICES, default=1)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

And an `UpdateAPIView`

```
class RequestDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Request.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RequestUpdateSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsAdminOrRequestOwner)
    name = 'request-detail'

    # TODO: send an email inform user that the request have been approve or reject
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.profile.role != 3:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {'detail': 'You do not have permission to perform this action'})

        return super().update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

What I need is to send an email to the owner of that `Request` instance. I have written a function to do that but it has to be called in `update()` method of `UpdateAPIView`

In order to send an email, it required the data from the `Request` instance that is being updated. The request data only contains information about `status`

My question is what is the proper way to get the `Request` instance inside the `UpdateAPIView`. My approach is to get the `id` from `kwargs` params and then query the `Request` instance that I needed.

Comment: `self.get_object()`?

Comment: yeah, it works. How stupid I am :((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `get_object` method:

```py
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # some logic

    instance = self.get_object()
    send_email(to=instance.owner.email, message='Your message')  # use your own send_email

    return super().update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```